# What is the right way to edit spark-env.sh before running spark-shell?

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark, config

I am running spark on my local windows machine. I am able to start spark shell successfully.

I want to edit the spark-env.sh file residing in conf/ folder. What is the right way to add values to the spark-env.sh file.

E.g If I want to add value to SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY variable how to do it?
Am getting confused between different answers that are available 
1. SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY="2G"
2. export

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `spark-env.sh` is a regular bash script intended for **Unix**, so on a Windows installation it will never get picked up.

On **Windows**, you'll need to have a `spark-env.cmd` file in the `conf` directory and instead use the following syntax :

```
set SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G
```

On **Unix**, the file will be called `spark-env.sh` and you will need to preprend each of your properties with `export` (e.g. : `export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G`)

Comment: Thank you! Creating spark-env.cmd in conf directory and setting the values as `set SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G` worked.

Answer (score 7):

You must have to use `export` to add any configuration in `*.sh` file. So in `spark-env.sh` file use following example,

```
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=192.165.5.1
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2g
#OR export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G
```

No need to use double quotes for values.