# Spark standalone cluster tires to access local python.exe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When executing a python application on a spark cluster I run into the following exception:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/04/07 10:57:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]17/04/07 10:57:07 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.2.113, executor 0): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\<local-user>\Anaconda2\python.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 13 more

17/04/07 10:57:07 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<redacted-absolute-path>.py", line 49, in <module>
    eco_rdd
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2139, in zipWithIndex
    nums = self.mapPartitions(lambda it: [sum(1 for i in it)]).collect()
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 809, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 192.168.2.113, executor 0): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\<local-user>\Anaconda2\python.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 13 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\<local-user>\Anaconda2\python.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 13 more
```

Somehow the cluster (on a remote pc in the same network) tries to access the local python (that is installed on my local workstation which executes the driver):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\<local-user>\Anaconda2\python.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

- Spark 2.1.0
- The spark standalone cluster is running on Windows 10
- The workstation is running on Windows 7
- Connecting to the cluster and executing tasks with `spark-shell` (interactive) works without problems
- Connecting to the cluster and executing tasks with `pyspark` (interactive) works without problems
- Running  from pycharm directly caused the exception above
- Using `spark-submit` to execute  caused a similar problem (=> trying to access my local python)
- is using findspark
- The PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON environment variables are set
- Python on cluster and workstation: Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Just a wild idea -- did you try to force `PYSPARK_PYTHON` in the executor conf, i.e. adding `spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON  C:\some\path\python.exe` in your `spark-defaults.conf` (or on the command-line via `--conf`)?

Comment: I tried to set that configuration in various different ways, but got the same error. In some cases it tried to execute the local driver with the remote python instance (=another exception than that one).
You have to set those configurations on the local workstation right? I tried to set it on both (local and remote) just to be sure.

Comment: Both env variables are used by the `spark-submit` utility; in theory, the value of `PYSPARK_PYTHON` should be used by the executors and it should refer to a Python install on the executors' machine; and the value of `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` (when present, otherwise defaulted to PYSPARK_PYTHON value) should be used by the driver, and it should refer to a Python install on the driver's machine *(which may be different from the `spark-submit` machine -- in `yarn-cluster` mode for instance!)*

Comment: Note that Spark 2.1 documentation mentions a way to choose Python using properties instead of env variables -- maybe the properties also exist in 1.6 and 2.0 but were not documented, maybe it's a new feature... http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html under `spark.pyspark.python` etc

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I just tried to add the `spark.pyspark.driver.python` and `spark.pyspark.python` properties as well. No change so far.
I mostly use variations of that command in my tests: `%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit --conf spark.pyspark.python=%PYSPARK_PYTHON% --conf spark.pyspark.driver.python=%PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON% --conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=%PYSPARK_PYTHON% --master spark://%SPARK_MASTER_HOST%:%SPARK_MASTER_PORT% --py-files some.zip <my-spark-application>.py`

Comment: I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300099/what-is-the-right-way-to-edit-spark-env-sh-before-running-spark-shell
But using `spark-env.cmd` to set the python environment didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution for my problem now. For my setup the problem was the findspark library. Removing allowed me to run all my tasks on the cluster.

If you have a similar problem but it's not findspark related I would point you to the comments from Samson Scharfrichter above.