# encountered a ERROR that Can't run program on pyspark

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark

I entered these commands on pyspark

```
 In [1]: myrdd = sc.textFile("Cloudera-cdh5.repo")
 In [2]: myrdd.map(lambda x:x.upper()).collect()
```

When i execute 'myrdd.map(lambda x:x.upper()).collect()',I encountered a ERROR

The following is ERROR info

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, tiger): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/python3": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 13 more
```

The file /usr/local/bin/python3 is exist on the disk

How can i solve the above error?

Comment: Check if execute permission is set for "/usr/local/bin/python3" from all users.

Comment: permission of /usr/loca/bin/python3 is  lrwxrwxrwx. It is a link of /usr/loca/bin/python3.5. python3.5's permission is  -rwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to give access permission on `/usr/local/bin/python3`  this path, you can use command `sudo chmod 777  /usr/local/bin/python3/*`.

I think this issue is occurred by variable PYSPARK_PYTHON, it is use to pointing python's location for every nodeyou can use below command

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: I have already set up PYSPARK_PYTHON variable to point /usr/local/bin/python3  in the ~/.bashrc file

Comment: then you can give the `777` permission to `/usr/local/bin/python3/*` and try it .

Comment: It is a link file of python3.5 with same directory. The permission is 777.but it still not okay for me

Comment: I run pyspark on cluster mode. i have elephant,monkey and tiger nodes.but tiger node doesn't have /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: @liuyashuai: You must have python install on all nodes

Comment: @HaPham Thank you。 it is okay when all nodes already installed python

Comment: @HaPham darn.. Thank you for the comment, it took me a full day to get it..

Answer (score 7):

For those using Windows:
Create a spark-env.cmd file in your conf directory and put the following line inside the spark-env.cmd file.

```
set PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Python39\python.exe
```

[This stack-overflow answer explains about setting environment variables for pyspark in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300099/what-is-the-right-way-to-edit-spark-env-sh-before-running-spark-shell)

Comment: Can you show me how to create the spark-env.cmd file?

Answer (score 3):

I am using Windows 10 and facing the same issue. I could it fix simply by coping  python.exe and renaming it to python3.exe and python.exe folder is set in the environment variable path.

Answer (score 0):

More "stupidly", rather than a permission issue, it can just be that you do not have python3 installed or the path variable for it may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set python as python3

```
sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3
python --version
```