# PYCHARM Error-- java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm

I am getting the below error while running a pyspark program on PYCHARM,
Error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified ......

The interpreter is recognizing the python.exe file and I have added the Content root in project structure.

I got a similar issue while running the same program before in on windows command prompt and solved it using [What is the right way to edit spark-env.sh before running spark-shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300099/what-is-the-right-way-to-edit-spark-env-sh-before-running-spark-shell)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a few posts for approximately this error message see [pycharm cannot run program is:q](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=pycharm%20cannot%20run%20program%20is%3aq). This one may be what you want [PyCharm error: Cannot run program, error=2, No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223548).  However I think there isn't a thread about your exact error message. I'm assuming this is PySpark specific so any details you could add to the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 36):

Before creating your spark session, set the following environment variables in your code:

```py
import os
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 24):

create an environment variable PYSPARK_PYTHON with value 'python' or the path to your respective python executable.

Comment: dude you are a `life saver` person. I have been struggling with it almost a week!

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to Environmental variable and within System variable set a new variable as `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and value as `python`

> PYSPARK_PYTHON=python

2. Add below codebits to your pyspark code

```
import os
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Also, after setting PYSPARK_PYTHON env var, you might need to restart whatever IDE / CMD Prompt you are using.