# Missing Python executable 'python3'

Tags: python, pyspark

I am running pyspark locally and had some issues due to something with the paths to python (when running python3 in command prompt I got an error, but when running python I would not. I have python 3 installed) I would get an java.io.IOException error when trying to run a pyspark job.

Now I have added

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

which solves my problem. However, this does not seem like the best solution. Do I then in every file have to add this at the beginning or is there a smarter solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PYCHARM Error-- java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68705417/pycharm-error-java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-python3-createprocess) also see: [environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260412/environment-variables-pyspark-python-and-pyspark-driver-python) you basically need to set those environment variables

Comment: To be found the regular way, your Python 3.x must be in the `PATH` variable inherited in the environment of the process running pyspark. Not offering this as an answer because I don't know how you are set up so I can't describe a solution, but start reading with [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403972/the-python-command-starts-the-the-wrong-version-of-the-python-interpreter) and follow the trail from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a file with the code that fix the problem and import it in your main file.

since you import it in the main file it will execute the code imported first then run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try linking `python3` to `python`?

```bash
PYTHON=$(which python)
sudo ln -s $PYTHON "$PYTHON"3
```

The `ln` command will generate a symbolic link to `python` in the same path where the shell is looking for `python3`.

Comment: What does it mean to link the two python versions?

Comment: you create a link to the python executable so when it looks for python3 it will go to python instead

Comment: So should I run this command in the command prompt?