# Getting error in Split function when using it inside Flatmap function in pycharm

Tags: python, pyspark, split, pycharm

When I tried to run the Pyspark program to just show the elements in the list using Pycharm community edition which uses split function as a space delimiter inside flatmap function, I got the below error. Could you please suggest me a solution. I am getting the error only if I am using split function inside flatmap as below.

```
b=a.flatMap(lambda line:line.split(";"))
```

I am using Pycharm community edition 2021.2.2 version, Spark 3.4.1 version, hadoop 3.3.6 version.

C:\Users\jagadeeswaran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:/Users/jagadeeswaran/PycharmProjects/spark1/spark2.py
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/08/29 22:40:11 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
a;1
b;2
c;3
d;4
e;5
23/08/29 22:40:19 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 12)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1140)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1074)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:159)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1111)
... 17 more
23/08/29 22:40:19 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 14)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1140)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1074)

Below is the code snippet I tried to run,

[code snippet]

```
import pyspark
# sql functions import
from pyspark.sql.functions import split,col
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
sc1 = SparkSession.builder.appName('flatmap() pyspark').getOrCreate()
data = ["a;1","b;2","c;3","d;4","e;5"]
a = sc1.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
for element in a.collect():
    print(element)

b=a.flatMap(lambda line:line.split(";"))
for element in b.collect():
    print(element)
```

I tried to install the Pyspark, Pyspark functions in settings of project Interpreter in pycharm and checked the environment variables too and those also fine. Actually I tried to run word count program but not worked.

Thank you!

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: This should solve your error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68705417/pycharm-error-java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-python3-createprocess